# PassPhrase is not valid in SharePoint 2013. Powershell not connecting to SharePoint farm to reset passphrase

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, administration

I have removed Project server instance from my SharePoint 2013 farm. After that when I tried to run the configuration wizard, I found that the old passphrase is not valid.

When I open powershell, the powershell is not connecting to the SharePoint farm. So, I cannot reset the PassPhrase.

I tried to create a new farm  with a different SharePoint config database and added the existing content databases to a new webapplication. The problem I face is, I dont know which content database belongs to which webapplication.

So, I have removed the servers from the farm again and I am trying to figure out the passphrase on what it could be and inquiring on who changed which piece.

Any ideas on how I could resolve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Nate

Ps: i have posted the same question in Microsoft forums too, I am sorry for the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove Project Server you will need to rebuild with a new config DB anyway.  MS doesn't support uninstall Project from SharePoint once it's installed, and there are no supported methods for removing all the references.  As a note - though it wont help you here, the recommendation is to just de-activate the features in use.

Now -if you have already removed all servers from your farm you won't be able to recover your pass phrase.  It's stored in the config DB somewhere but I couldn't begin to tell you how to get at it, and even if you did you would need a method for decrypting it (PowerShell ConvertFrom-SecureString may possibly work, but again that's only if you can find the string to begin with).

If you have already created a new farm - you can view the site collections in the previous content databases.  To do that you can use Central Administration (or PowerShell).

1. Make sure the databases are connected and online in SQL Server
2. In Central Administration go to Backup and Restore --> Granular Backup --> Recover data from an unattached content database.
3. Enter your SQL server instance where databases are connected and then enter one of the databases names you need access too.
4. Once SharePoint connects to the database you can select Browse Content and see the Site Collections stored in the database.

When working with PowerShell you can use the following to list sites in database:

```
$myOldDatabase = Get-SPContentDatabase -ConnectAsUnattachedDatabase  -DatabaseName <DatabaseName> -DatabaseServer <DatabaseServer>
$myOldDatabase.sites
```

Now once you have a list of what sites are in what database you can then go back and re-associate those databases with the proper web application.

**NOTE:**
If you have multiplie databases assigned to a web application you need to find out which database has the root site collection and attach this database first.  This will simply be the site collection with the same URL as the web application. (i.e. if your web applicaiton is http://myapp.domain.com then you want to mount the database with the site collection url of http://myapp.domain.com)